# How to show alert view when we access contact in iOS application at very first time when we install application on iOS device?

Tags: ios

When we install new app on iOS device, it ask for as a Alert view as a "Do you want to access iPhone contacts in your application. But when I am installing the app first time in iOS device, it is not showing any alert view, So How user will know that he can access iPhone contacts in  my application.

Any Solution,

Thank You

Comment: then, what you are doing to get the alert ?

Comment: iOS device shows Alert view when we access iPhone Contacts.But it is not showing in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will ask by the apple when you try to use address book.

in the future if you wants to show you can use the following code

```
     -(void)requestAddressBookAccess
{
    ViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(self.addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
                                             {
                                                 if (granted)
                                                 {
                                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                                     });
                                                 }
                                                 else{
                                                 }
                                             });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS shows that alert when you try to access the address book for the first time. So to show it, just read something from the address book.

However, it may be a better experience to "pre-ask" using your own alert first, if you want to give the user information about *why* you need access to contacts.

This approach was recently discussed [here](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2014/04/27/asking-pre-permission/).

Note that, during development, if you ask permissions in your app, then delete and reinstall the app, the permissions are remembered and will not be requested again. You have to go to Settings - General - Reset and reset the location and privacy settings.